# Chemical properties of dicopper (I) tetraiodomercurate (II)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, mercury

This is a continuation from my  [previous post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/149787/how-to-use-sodium-thiosulfate-for-fixing-dicopper-i-tetraiodomercurate-ii).

Where can I find information on the chemical properties of $\ce{Cu2[HgI4]}$? I found a mention that in reaction with $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ in presence of acid it gives $\ce{HgS}$.

Comment: I came from your previously asked question. While it was a good idea to create a separate question, you should link your original question here lest some users feel you haven't done enough research.

Comment: Check II of [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59295/are-complex-ions-thermochromic/59324?r=SearchResults#59324)